# JQuery slideDown not working after stopped slideUp

Tags: jquery

My setup is ridiculously simple:

HTML:

```
<p>
    test
</p>
```

JS:

```
$('p').slideUp(2000);

// later, while still sliding up
$('p').stop().slideDown();
```

Instead of stopping the slideUp motion and starting to slide down, it just stops and nothing happens. When inverting the problem (stopping slideDown and doing slideUp), everything works as expected!

I tested in the latest versions of Firefox and Chromium with jQuery 1.9.1.

[JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rFHUx/1/)

Is this a bug? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `slideDown` expect the element to be completely invisible. As ryan said, you will have in this case to use `.animate()` to have the desired behaviour. See this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rFHUx/7/)** to see what you have to do to have the exact same behaviour of `slideUp` (set padding, margin and height to 0)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know or see in the doc that it expects 0 height... In this case, adding `true, true` to `stop` is probably the easiest solution.
Edit: Changed my mind; animations are better (prevent jumping).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a CSS height problem. Instead, set explicit heights and call [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) yourself.

```
var p = $('p'), h = p.height();
p.animate({ height: 0}, 1100);
setTimeout(function(){
    p.stop().animate({ height: h});
}, 1000);
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rFHUx/3/)**

Comment: Also make `padding: '0 2em'`. You can also use `height: 'auto'` to make it easier : http://jsfiddle.net/rFHUx/6/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `true,true` Check updated fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/rFHUx/2/

Comment: Works but sure is ugly

Comment: Works as expected, but causes "jumps", so I'll go with the `animate` solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
// 1. Solution

function loop() {
 $('p').slideUp(1000,function(){
  $('p').slideDown(1000,function(){
   loop();
  });
 });       
}
loop();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Aveendra/bkFDm/ fiddle here

OR

```
// 2. Solution
$('p').slideUp(1000).delay(500).slideDown(1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Aveendra/EcDQd/ fiddle here

Comment: This is not what he his expecting. He wants to stop the animation "in the middle" and resize back the element.

Comment: Exactly. My problem was caused by hovering and dehovering quickly.